# How to uninstall any software from ubuntu 20.04 LTS using Terminal?

Tags: intellij-idea, apt-get, ubuntu-20.04

I install intelliJ Idea community in my ubuntu 20.04 system. And by mistake i disabled the android option.. so i wanted to reinstall it.
So i type
"**sudo apt-get remove** "
But it always shown
**E: unable to locate the package**

And It is not only for this software,  it cannot locate any software

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt list --installed 
sudo apt remove name_app
sudo apt-get remove name_app 
sudo apt remove name_app1 name_app2
```

Answer (score -1):

first, execute the following two lines to ensure you don't have a broken package issue.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

if we are facing any error, comment below with the issue.
most of all will be resolved when you execute the above two lines. you will not get the issue with **sudo apt-get --purge remove** either

a simple way to uninstall any software on ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove app_name

example

sudo apt-get --purge remove obs-studio
```

Finally, once again

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: Now why on earth would I want to potentially upgrade a package I'm looking to purge? Updating and upgrading should be done afterwards

Comment: It is always better to update & upgrade `before` and `after` removing a package to ensure you are not adding any extra work. I faced it. I purged some packages, but I ended up getting dependency errors or broken package errors. So, It is best to update & upgrade  ****before & after***

Answer (score -1):

To find the exact package name in the system

1. **dpkg --list | grep package-name**
2. to remove the package and also its config files
   **sudo apt-get remove ––purge package-name**

if this didnt work for you . you can remove and purge later in 2 steps

1. **sudo apt-get remove  package-name**
2. follow below step a.
   Note: if you do just remove it won't delete the config files

a) if you have already removed package to remove config files and delete package cache completely follow below steps

1. **sudo -i**
2. **apt purge package-name**